# jquery prepend to textarea text()

Tags: jquery, text, textarea, prepend

I have a text area.  I can set the text of it with

```
$("#mytextarea").text("foo")
```

I can prepend to the text area like this:

```
$("#mytextarea").prepend("foo")
```

But I cannot prepend to the jquery text() object like this:

```
$("#mytextarea").text().prepend("foo")
```

The reason I want to do this is so that if my user gets me to prepend this text:

```
$("#mytextarea").prepend("<script>alert('lol i haxed uuu!')</script>")
```

...the script executes and I lose.

Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to modify the `val()` property:

```
$('#mytextarea').val(function(index, old) { return '...' + old; });
```

By the way, the correct way to get the contents of the textarea is to call `val()`, not `text()`:

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following URL for jQuery .val() API documentation for more details-

http://api.jquery.com/val/